# How to configure Apache to listen some different port?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, port80

I am facing problem in starting  XAMPP. First of all it gives me error messages in RED when i start XAMPP control panel. When i click on START APACHE, it starts it but when i open localhost it gives me the following error message.

> Not Found
>
> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

I have tried various ways to resolve this problem but it isn't solved yet. Kindly guide me.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hit the "Config" button?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed my PORT from 80 to 90, but still its not working

Comment: "Not working" means what, exactly? What are you trying to access? If you're on port 90, URLs should be like `http://localhost:90/...`

Comment: Thank you so much, I was missing :90 at the end of URL. Its working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checklist

- first run XAMPP installer by UAC(User Account Control) and Antivirus off and run it as admin
- uninstall previous XAMP installation
- turn off IIS temporarily (which will use default port 80)
- change the port to some free valid port by following below guide

  - summary (Locate the file **httpd.conf**. This file should be found in C:\xampp\apache\conf folder or via config button in XAMPP control panel and search for 80 port and change it to something like 1234

http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp

Answer (score 0):

check services.msc if web deployment agent service is running.

check if IIS is running, stop it.

Comment: A little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As some solutions may suggest you turn off the IIS or some windows related services, you should therefore take precaution since there are possibilities of stopping very useful user process

Comment: This is a good point but does not address the question itself. Consider commenting on one of the other answers.